# Access Refresh Form

Tags: sql, forms, ms-access, vba, refresh

I have a simple access form with a record-set and some checkboxes which refer to certain fields in the query used for the record source.

There is also a command button which, when pressed, adds any field which has the associated checkbox's set to true to the query SQL. It then deletes the existing query and creates it again using the new SQL statement.

That is all working as expected, however I can't seem to get the form to reload the new query. I have tried Me.Requery and Me.Refresh but neither work, I have to manually close the form and reopen it to get the new fields to display.

Does anyone have any ideas how I can achieve this without closing the form and then repopening?

Thanks

________EDITED___________

```
Private Sub Command28_Click()
On Error Resume Next
Dim strSQL As String
Dim strSQL_2 As String
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Const conQUERY_NAME As String = "qry_pick_search"

For Each ctl In Me.Controls
    If ctl.ControlType = acCheckBox Then
        If ctl.Value Then
            strSQL = strSQL & "Picks." & ctl.Tag & ", "
        End If
    End If
Next

CurrentDb.QueryDefs.Delete conQUERY_NAME

On Error GoTo Err_Command28_Click

strSQL_2 = "SELECT Picks.Type, " & strSQL & " Picks.part, Count(Picks.ID) AS CountOfID FROM Picks GROUP BY Picks.Type, " & strSQL & " Picks.part HAVING (((Picks.Type) = [Forms]![frm_picks]![select_type]) And ((Picks.part) = [Forms]![frm_picks]![select_part])) Or ((([Forms]![frm_picks]![select_part]) Is Null) And (([Forms]![frm_picks]![select_type]) Is Null)) Or (((Picks.Type) = [Forms]![frm_picks]![select_type]) And (([Forms]![frm_picks]![select_part]) Is Null)) Or (((Picks.part) = [Forms]![frm_picks]![select_part]) And (([Forms]![frm_picks]![select_type]) Is Null)) ORDER BY Picks.Type, Picks.part;"

Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef(conQUERY_NAME, strSQL_2)

Form.Requery

Exit_Command28_Click:
  Exit Sub

Err_Command28_Click:
  MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation, "Error in Command28_Click()"
  Resume Exit_Command28_Click

End Sub
```

Comment: Please post your code for the command button.

Comment: If you wanted to, you could just build a form filter and update that. My code has: Me.FilterOn = True
Then anytime I touch the filter (i.e. Me.Filter = "XYZ") the form is automatically requeried.

Comment: Agree.  My sense is there is an easier approach.

Comment: @Smandoli See the above edit

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn See the above edit

Comment: Not sure what your edit is about. Is that the code that doesn't work? If so, replace your line 'Form.Requery' with 'Me.RecordSource = conQUERY_NAME' and that will work. HOWEVER, I would use a filter rather than changing the querydef.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are editing the SQL on the fly, why not just assign it directly to the form?

```
Me.RecordSource=strSQL_2
```

(Note that no requery is needed. Changing a forms recordsource causes accesss to automatically requery)

Thats a method I've worked in the past and it works just fine.